# How do I add Material-UI to a JSFiddle project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I can add [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) using NPM, but I can't seem to find out how to load and/or use the script when using systems like JSFiddle or SO's own code editor.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ChimeraZen/xuh98mLg/)

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/92vj3kv9mo working on codesandbox.io

Comment: codesandbox.io seems to have a different setup than JSFiddle, the SO code editor and CodePen.io. Any suggestions on how to achieve using MUI on any of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
const {
  Button,
  ...
} = window['material-ui'];
```

It should be `MaterialUI` instead of `window['material-ui']`, I've reported the issue here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12387